# Has any Indian national travelled to Stockholm via London Heathrow from Colombo

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, lhr

My travel itinerary is India to Colombo, Colombo to London Heathrow (Srilankan Airlines Terminal3) and Heathrow to Stockholm(British Airways Terminal 5). I will be staying in airport for a total of 4 hrs and 45 mins in London Heathrow

I am not sure if I need a transit visa. I have Swedish residence permit. Has anyone travelled this route without transit visa.

I checked the link https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/no and it mentions that I can transit without visa. It would be good if someone who has travelled this route can give some insights.

Comment: Is this all on one booking (one PNR)?

Comment: Yes, it is one booking reference.